# jQuery UI regenerate (zombie) draggable elements

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'd like to know how to create draggable elements using jQuery UI that once they are dragged and dropped into another container, regenerate the same item. For example, I can drop a button from container A to container B, and once I do that, the same button (a clone) re-emerges in container A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to go about this would be to go with an append or prepending a new element to an existing anchor.

```
var newElement = $("<div id='home'></div>").draggable( { snap: '.droppable', revert: 'invalid' } );
    $("#homearea").append(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the drop event with a custom function:

```
$('.selector').droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

When the item is dropped in the new container, insert a clone into the original container. You can make new elements using jQery:

```
var listItem = $("<li></li>");
```

References:

- [UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)
- [jQuery core](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument)